# R: Using lapply on rbinom with different arguments for prob

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following problem:

I have an array X with length n, which contains some positive numbers.
I now want to contruct a second array Y which should contain random numbers from a bernoulli distribution, but the probability of success is some m(X[i], theta) every time.

I can do it in a for loop but I want to know if it's possible to do it in one line.

I tried something like:

```
X = sample(c(seq(20)), replace = TRUE)
m<-function(x,theta) return(x*theta)
Y = lapply(lapply(X, m, theta=2), rbinom, n=1, size=1)
```

but it doesn't work in an form I tried.

I'm a real R beginner, so maybe the answer is easy, but I couldn't figure out what to search for to find something that helps me...

Comment: I know. I wanted to use some more simple stuff to get it work first but I guess that was the problem...

Comment: @JenniferGroß  Your function `m` returns a value greater than 1.  So, change your function.  Also, can you show the working `for` loop?

Comment: The only way to find out is to try/read docs. No need to run loops on vectorized functions in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am translating your code into

```
X <- sample(c(seq(20)), replace = TRUE)
m <- function(x,theta) return(x*theta)
prob  <- lapply(X, m, theta=2)
Y = unlist(lapply(prob, rbinom, n=1, size=1))
```

At the moment we are getting all `NA` for `Y`. But, provided `prob` is appropriate, there is nothing wrong with your code. For example,

```
prob <- 1:10 / 10
Y = unlist(lapply(prob, rbinom, n=1, size=1))
```

is giving meaningfull result.

Note that there is no need to use `lapply` to get `prob`. Simply do

```
prob <- m(X, theta)
```

is fine, because the `"*"` operator is vectorized.

Comment: Thanks, this it is working now.
Also thank you for the advanced advice using less lapply, I appreciate that

Comment: `rbinom(n=length(prob), size=1, prob = prob)`